# Adding or Changing a node in a document MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an existing document that may or may not have an embedded node "cls" like this:

```
product { 
   _id: ..,
   product_id: "myuniqueid",
   name: "some name",
   cls: { some data }
}
```

Now, what I need:

1. if product does not exist, nothing happens
2. if product exists and cls exists, cls part is updated
3. if product exists and cls does not exist, cls part is added to that product

What I found was nothing happens if I set `upsert = false`. However, I would be inclined to believe that the `upsert` applies to the embedding doc (product) and not the embedded one (cls).

So basically I write:

```
public static UpdateResult upsert(MongoCollection<Document> coll, Bson filter, Document doc, boolean upsert) {
    BasicDBObject action = new BasicDBObject("$set", doc);
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(upsert);
    return coll.updateOne(filter, action, options);
}
```

And then use:

```
product.append("cls", clsDoc);
DBUtil.upsert(products, new BasicDBObject("product_id", pid), product, false);
```

It does not appear to be updating anything, at least if the cls does not exist yet. So, it is almost as if the `upsert` option applies to the cls node and not the embedding product. The MongoDB documentation is not conclusive on the matter.

I could probably change `upsert` to true and make product_id a unique index as to guarantee that no alien products get inserted. But what I really are looking for is an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to "create" something when the criteria is not matched then you do not want ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) ever. That is the sole purpose as you are basically saying *"Here is what makes a 'unique' document, and if you didn't find one then create one for me"*. That is not what your logic suggests. It is in fact a lot more simple than that.

All you really want is :

1. Find the product or do not
2. When you find something, then set this field to this value

As basically your own 2nd and 3rd points work out to be point 2 above. And nothing here suggests *"Create a new document where not found"*, which is the "upsert" behavior, and therefore you omit it.

So essentially, just [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

```
collection.updateOne(
    new BasicDBObject("product_id", pid),
    new BasicDBObject("$set",
        new BasicDBObject("cls", justClsValue)
    )
);
```

And it really cannot be more simple as those are the basic mechanics.

The other really nice thing you will see is if what you want to set "cls" to is exactly the same as what is already there, then in fact the `$set` operation actually does nothing, as the update is smart enough to realize it's the same and not attempt to change the data. It still reports the "match", but updated statistics behind the scenes say no update in this case.

Comment: Okay! So I should directly add the new BasicDBObject("cls", justClsValue) to the action instead of first adding this to the embedding product! Thanks. Happy I learned something today.

Comment: @dexter The great big ambiguty in your question is *"what is the data in `product`?"* which is just presented as a mysterious variable with no explaination. The point of `$set` ( and other update operators ) is it allows you specify "field paths" that you actually want to update with something, as opposed to just overwriting the whole document. So if all you want to do is "set cls where I found a product" then that is all you do. The other "great big ambiguity" is, is "product" the main document or is it an array of "embedded items" within the document? Mor of a tip on how to ask really.